# Remove string "foo" and leading and trailing white space using a single regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Title says it all

- Single Regex
- remove leading white space
- remove trailing white space

ie.

```
"  fooHello World" => "Hello World"
"fooBing space in the middlefoo  " => "Bing space in the middle"
"  foo " => ""
" fooHellofoo  " => "Hello"
```

Comment: *Happy programmers' day!!*

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`trim()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) to remove the leading/trailing whitespace.

You can use [`replace()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) to target `foo` via regex and remove it. Try running the snippet below:

```js
const trimAndRemoveFoo = (str) => {
  return str.trim().replace(/foo/g, '');
}

// log trimAndRemoveFoo function with sample strings
console.log(trimAndRemoveFoo("  fooHello World"));
console.log(trimAndRemoveFoo("fooBing space in the middlefoo  "));
console.log(trimAndRemoveFoo("  foo "));
console.log(trimAndRemoveFoo(" fooHellofoo  "));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `replace` with regex search, with the following regex `/\W*foo\W*/g`

```js
const strs = [
  "  fooHello World",
  "fooBing space in the middlefoo  ",
  "  foo ",
  " fooHellofoo  "
];

const results = strs.map((str) => {
  return str.replace(/\W*foo\W*/g, '');
});

console.log(results)
```

Comment: Why is the downgrade?